# Manually added table view causes gray navigation bar and tab bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created an app using the "tabbed application" template.

I renamed the top view controllers for both initial tabs (initially "First" and "Second"), and embedded each in a navigation controller.

Next, I dragged a UITableView into one of the view controller's main view, resized it to fit perfectly, and set constraints for:

1. "Leading space to container margin"
2. "Trailing space to container margin"
3. "Vertical spacing to top layout guide"
4. "Vertical spacing to bottom layout guide"

Next, I wrote code in the view controller to handle the table view (set delegate, data source, adopt protocols, register cell class, etc.)

Also, I implemented a "detail" view controller (xib based, not present in the storyboard) which instance I push into the navigation when a table row is selected.

**The Problem:** For the view controller that has a table view only (second image below), both the navigation bar and tab bar appear in a darker, medium gray (instead of the default "almost white"):

[image: Unchanged, original view controller]

[image: View controller with table view manually added]

[image: View controller instantiated from separate xib]

I have tried changing the navigation bar's `translucent` property, and setting the view controller view's `backgroundColor` to white, but nothing changes.

I know this has to do with the (overly complex un twisted) way view controllers behave since iOS 7, but I can't quite find the solution anywhere...

Comment: did you found a solution? I'km having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remeber. This was a minimal project I made to demonstrate state preservation/restoration...

Comment: But I think it's related to one of the many UI pitfalls of the transition to iOS 7...

Comment: Well, I end up deleting my tableviewcontroller e creating a new one that worked. Thanks